# Cant send SMS from LG devices

Tags: android, sms, lg

My App is sending an auto sms. The thing is that it works great on all phones but not on LG devices.
thats my code:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null,
                null);
}
```

And thats the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lge.mdm.uimanager.adapter.LGMDMUIMessageAdapter.isAllowSendMessage(LGMDMUIMessageAdapter.java:50)
at com.lge.mdm.MDMInterfaceImpl.isAllowSendMessage(MDMInterfaceImpl.java:108)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SmsManager.java:354)
at berg.royi.donotdisturbe.free.service.DNDservice.sendSMS(DNDservice.java:120)
at berg.royi.donotdisturbe.free.service.DNDservice.onHandleIntent(DNDservice.java:95)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

What is this "LGMDMUIMessageAdapter.isAllowSendMessage"?  How do I allow it?
I saw somewere somthing about needing to add an optional field when sending sms from LG devices but that was it, no other explenation.
Thanks!

Comment: Its the device specific driver that actually sends the sms.  If it has an NPE, either their driver is screwed up and needed to be reset (which a crash should do), or your sending it some data that may cause it to crash.  The thing that comes to mind is if message is null, divideMessage may return null rather than a valid array.  Or if phoneNumber is null it could die badly.

Comment: Thanks, but i tested it and they both are not null. What else could it be?

Comment: Have you tried passing in non-null pending intents?  It would be a bug to require them, but their driver may be buggy.